# Speed up Jupyter server spawn like on Kaggle

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

Currently, I am developing a jupyterhub server inside a Kubernetes cluster, hence using "Kubespawner" with autoscale on a cloud platform. It took a while to spawn a notebook server due to the nature of "auto scale" which is going to scale up when required to have more Notebook servers.

Could anyone please give me advice to gain spawn speed similar to Kaggle? because currently what I have will takes around 3-5 minutes just to spawn a notebook server. While Kaggle could spawn a notebook server just at 30seconds max. It is very impressive compared to mine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your setup? Which docker images are you using? How is it built and how often is it updated? Is it just you using the cluster or are there others? Are people using the cluster regularly or is it pretty infrequent?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, the image is: gcr.io/kaggle-images/python and some prebuilt images. Still in dev phase, so could be only few users using the cluster.

Comment: can you explain more about how your cluster is set up though? is this zero2jupyterhub? binderhub? something else? (links/code please!) you're kind of asking for a comprehensive guide to kubernetes boot performance if you don't provide more specifics ;)

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, I just created a custom deployment by utilizing `Kubespawner`. It is quite simple, just spawns pods when jupyterhub creating server, and we accommodate the pods in "Cluster auto scaller" manner. The problem is on the "Cluster auto scaler" speed I guess. Now I am in the middle of experimenting with "Overprovision" my cluster for "Auto scale performance". Not sure whether it is correct approach though.

Comment: Pre-heated kernels sound like a solution to your problem; I have not seen a jupyterhub setup, but there is an existing code base for jupyter viola which you could re-purpose, see [this blog post](https://blog.jupyter.org/need-for-speed-voil%C3%A0-edition-a9e1300ab3b2).

Comment: +1 to pre-heating. the other thing is just that nodes cache docker layers. if you have a larger number of users with a small number of image options, you're more likely to boot quickly as you're more likely to be assigned a warm node with the image already pulled. If you're getting a fresh node or if you have a large number of images users are frequently switching between (thus invalidating the cache), you'll need to pull the full image more often. Keeping images small, building multiple flavors off the same base, and physically colocating your registry with the cluster also helps.

Comment: zero2jupyterhub has a guide for [optimizing performance here](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/administrator/optimization.html), including how to pre-pull images. If you haven't already checked out zero2jupyterhub I'd definitely consider using their setup directly :)

Comment: @krassowski, wow that doesn't cross to my mind. Will dive deep into there soon.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, yes, have configured the pre-pulled image with "overprovision" on the Autoscaler. Just comes with costly consequences. Just need to bring the "Pre-heated" things. Seem my approach already match your reference on Zero2jupyterhub both about "overprovision" and "pre-pull". Still prefer the manual approach over helm chart :). Thanks for both of you for inspiring me.

Comment: Btw, I got an idea to change the "pre-pulled" image instead of using Pod/pause container approach, using cloud AMI seems will be much faster. Any more inspiration from you guys? I am using AWS EKS btw.

Comment: I don't have any tricks up my sleeve. We run a few clusters build off the [daskhub helm chart](https://github.com/dask/helm-chart/tree/main/daskhub) and the boot time is I would say in the 30-60s range. Sometimes it's longer, but usually it's pretty quick. Generally our experience has been that the more users you have and the more regularly the cluster is used the smoother the initial boots go. It could be that AWS is slow to grant you a new node when you request them infrequently.